# Is there a way to find out which condition (out of many by using or) in "if" is evaluated to true because of which it entered inside the if?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an if statement, let's say:

```py
if cond1 or cond2 or cond3:  
     do_something()
```

Can I find out which among these three conditions (cond1,cond2 and cond3) was true because of which it entered inside and executed do_something()?

P.S: I'm looking for answers which doesn't suggest me to use another 2 if's below my if to find out which was true.

Comment: You need to post some code, preferably a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). This will help others to help you.

Comment: Not without re-evaluating in some manner. Python reduces the entire expression to a single value and its the truth value of that final thing that matters.

Comment: @tdelaney thnx. I guess I'll just have to use another 1 or 2 if statements below that.

Comment: it is better to use 3 different conditions if you need to act differently, else the priority and precedence for each condition may affect your response action.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it in a for loop:

```
for i, j in enumerate((cond1, cond2, cond3)):
    if j:
        do_something()

        print(i)  #Do whatever you want to do with the 1st condition that was true
        break
```